# Centered and fixed navigation

Tags: css, menu, navigation, fixed

I have the css below, which makes my navigation bar be centered.
However, i want to add the following line "position:fixed", but if i do so, the navigation bar will no longer be centered, and will no longer have the border lines stretched all across the screen.

Any suggestions ? (Thanks !)

```
.navbar{
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    border-width:1px 0;
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center; } 

.navbar li{
    display:inline; } 

.navbar a{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:10px; }

body {
    padding-left: 0em;  padding-bottom: 0em;
    color: white;
    background-color: #708090; 
    font-family: Georgia, Times, serif}
```

Comment: does my answer not work for you?

Comment: I would buy you a beer if you were in the vicinity :)i've been looking for a solution since 2 days ago. thanks !

Comment: If my answer is correct, you should accept it by clicking the tick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">First Nav Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Second Nav Item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Third Nav Item</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav { 
  position: fixed;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%; height:40px;
  line-height:40px;
  text-align: center; }

nav li { display: inline; }
```